# How can i delete multiple objects from HKHealthStore?

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I know there are these methods, according to [Apple HealthKit Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/saveObjects:withCompletion:)

```
Working with HealthKit Objects

deleteObject:withCompletion:
saveObject:withCompletion:
saveObjects:withCompletion:
```

I'm looking for something like this:
`deleteObjects:withCompletion:`

Or a way to delete multiple objects from `HKHealthStore` without calling `deleteObject:withCompletion:` multiple times.

Comment: Why don`t you want to call it multiple times? You could do it with a for loop, count the number of calls of the completion function, and once it reaches the number of objects you wanted to delete, call the `real` completion function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 8, the only way to delete multiple objects was to invoke `deleteObject:withCompletion` multiple times.  However, in iOS 9 there are two new methods available to delete multiple objects at a time.  Try using `deleteObjects:withCompletion:` or `deleteObjectsOfType:predicate:withCompletion:`.